# Application Page Error

Tags: application-pages

I created SharePoint 2013 Empty Project. I added Application Page, and I used webservice in page. When I running the page I get this error:

[image]

I added my ULS log. How can I solve this?

> UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres...   d21c3a9d-8383-f0d1-7044-7c37d99ee4b0
>
> UserProfileProperty_WCFLogging::Begin ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel
>
> Application error when access /_layouts/15/test/entegrasyon.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   at test.Layouts.test.Entegrasyon.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> ...(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>
> UserProfileProperty_WCFLogging :: End UserProfileApplication.GetProperties
>
> Cleanup of Orphan Systems in server servername
>   NerioCluster : Got Lease until 10/22/2015 13:00:39 for net.tcp://servername/630210/AdminComponent1/Services/InvokerService

Answer (score 1):

There is a null object being accessed in your Page_Load method according the logs below:

Debug the Page_Load method by setting a breakpoint at the begining of the method. 
Without looking at the actual code in the Page_Load method it is not clear what your code is doing in the method.

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/test/entegrasyon.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at test.Layouts.test.Entegrasyon.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```